# Cannot detect wifi networks around

Tags: networking, wifi, xfce, manjaro

When I first installed Manjaro, it asked me to connect to a Wifi network, so I connected to my Wifi at home and I have been connected ever since and everything was fine.

Yesterday was my first day at Uni with my new laptop and it was also my first time to try to connect to another wifi network. I noticed, that my network manager doesn't show me any other available networks other than the one from my home, eventhough there were definetetly other available ones around.

I have installed two little wifi elements on the bottom right corner, and I guess both are telling me I am not connected to any wifi apapter/port or what ever its called in english (Schnittstelle in german), eventhough I can connect to my wifi network at home. But I wouldn't even know how to activate it or further check whether it's activated or not.

when I checked lspci -v I found this:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595
Physical Slot: 0
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities:
Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

Kind regards,
Mr. Quaki

Comment: The tutorial [How to manage a WiFi connection from the command line](https://web.archive.org/web/20191031084501/http://xmodulo.com/manage-wifi-connection-command-line.html) might help. Since your wifi worked before, I would assume you have the correct drivers. Note: You may need to use `sudo iwconfig` rather than just `iwconfig`.

Comment: hmmm I used this 
https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections 
and it actually worked. But what do I do if I want to connect to something like eduroam, where I need to additionally enter username and password?

Comment: If eduroam is what's described on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam), they have a [Configuration Assistant Tool](https://cat.eduroam.org/) for several systems, including Linux. Click "About eduroam CAT" in the "About" menu on that page for a list of supported systems. Don't know about connecting to other services requiring un/pw without some client like at provided by eduroam, although a bit in the eduroam help faq suggests it's possible; see the "FAQ" item in the "Help" menu on the same page. Note: I know nothing about eduroam; I just dug up this info on it. :)

Comment: yea thanks david Ive read about that I hope it'll work, I will check it out on Monday. But could you please just tell me: Is connecting through the terminal by command the usual way to connect to a new Wifi with Network Manager, or does the Network Manager have a GUI to do that?

Comment: According to their [networking info](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Networking#Using_a_GUI_Tool), most editions of Manjaro provide a GUI tool for the purpose. To my knowledge, most Linux distros have GUIs for managing networking as well.

Comment: Since Manjaro is based on Arch, you might want to take a look at the [Arch info on wireless network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless) if info specifically for Manjaro isn't helpful.